# определить нажатие на элемент над которым находится другой элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, click

Приветствую

У меня ситуация - есть html код

```
<div class = 'block'>
    <img src = '...'>
</div>
```

и к нему листы стилей:

```
.block:after {
// полупрозрачный блок, который лежит полностью над img
}
```

Я хочу определить, что пользователь нажимает мышкой по картинке

```
$('.block img').on('click', function(e){});
```

не срабатывает, потому что мешает этот полупрозрачный `:after`

Можно ли это как-то обойти?

Те варианты, которые мне пришли в голову, не очень нравятся:
1) вместо `article:after` использовать некоторую оболочку/обертку

```
<div class = 'shell'><img></div>
```

и обращаться к ней

```
$('.shell').on('click', function(e){});
```

недостаток - не хочется плодить лишние теги

2) отслеживать нажатия на `.article` и обрабатывать координаты нажатия, проверять, соответствуют ли они координатам img

недостаток - много лишнего js кода, возможно изменение кода, если буду менять устройство `.article`

Есть ли еще какие-то способы? Или все таки склониться к 1-ому, как самому простому и очевидному?

**P.S.**

я внутрь картинке добавляю тень, img не позволяет это делать напрямую через свойство `box-shadow`, поэтому приходится над картинкой создавать невидимый блок и к нему применять тень (сейчас это `:after`, поскольку не требует дополнительных тегов)

Comment: ну ваш псевдокласс `after` полностью прикрывает картинку? и еще его размеры больше или ровны размерам картинки?

Comment: `$('.block').on('click', function(e){$(this).children('img')});` так не подойдет. Я в JS не силен но, так будет выбран `img` который вам нужен. Но могу ошибатся

Comment: нет - так я получу доступ к картинке, но нажать я могу не на картинку (скажем она занимает лишь часть '.block', а где-нибудь сбоку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте к after свойство pointer-events: none;

```
 .block:after {
  pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Comment: просто гениально!

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте к `.block:after` [правило](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) `pointer-events: none;`